# Как прокрутить массив кнопкой в + и в - в JS

Tags: javascript

Сделал вот такой велосипед! при прокрутке в положительную сторон проблем нет. прокрутке в обратную сторону появляются неопределенные элементы как этого избежать ? или что я сделал не правильно.

```
<style>
  body {
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  #box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #f108f1;
    background-color: black;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <button onclick="as.back()"></button>
  <button onclick="as.go()"></button>

  <script>
    let as = {
      color: ['red', '#f108f1', 'green'],
      index: 0,
      st: function (aa) {
        let box = document.getElementById('box')
        box.style.backgroundColor = aa;
      },

      go: function () {
        if (this.index == this.color.length - 1) {
          this.index = 0
        } else {
          this.index++
        }
        this.st(this.color[this.index])
      },
      // здесть при нажатии берется 2 неопредиленных елемна масива 
      back: function () {
        if (this.index < 0) {
          this.index = this.color.length
        } else {
          this.index--
        }
        this.st(this.color[this.index])
        
        console.log(this.color[this.index])
      }

    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: или скажите как задать генератор чтоб он при вызове выводил числа от 0 до допустим 10  и при равенстве 10 начинал крутить заново с 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код рабочий, за исключением ошибки в методе back().
Последний элемент имеет индекс на единицу меньше, чем размер массива, поэтому правильное выражение: `this.index = this.color.length - 1`.

Код можно немного упростить:

```js
var as = {
  color: ['red', '#f108f1', 'green'],
  index: 0,

  set: function() {
    let box = document.getElementById('box');
    box.style.backgroundColor = this.color[this.index];
  },
  go: function() {
    this.index = ++this.index == this.color.length ? 0 : this.index;
    this.set();
  },
  back: function() {
    this.index = --this.index < 0 ? this.color.length - 1 : this.index;
    this.set();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: aqua;
}

#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #f108f1;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
<button onclick="as.back()">-</button>
<button onclick="as.go()">+</button>
```

Comment: Да отлично! Спасибо. и я тоже пришел к этому решению и упрощению через тернарный оператор.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let as = {
  color: ['red', '#f108f1', 'green'],
  index: 0,
  set: function() {
    box.style.backgroundColor = this.color[this.index];
  },
  go: function() {
    this.index = (this.index + 1) % this.color.length;
    this.set();
  },
  back: function() {
    this.index = (this.index - 1 + this.color.length) % this.color.length;
    this.set();
  }
}
```

```css
#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #f108f1;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
  <button onclick="as.back()">&lt;</button>
  <button onclick="as.go()">&gt;</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Красивый вариант. Сам очень люблю сложение по модулю, но в некоторых задачах приходилось отказываться в пользу тернального оператора из-за производительности.

Comment: @LaukhinAndrey, ваш вариант с тернарным оператором намного читабельней чем вариант с модулем. В проектах, где работает несколько людей я бы выбрал вариант с тернарным. Правда мне казалось, что операции с модулем быстрее чем тернарные.